# Same Origin Policy Error , jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, json, http-post, same-origin-policy

I am developing the front-end(html-jquery) and back-end(php) of a Web Service. I am developing in my localhost using XAMPP(Apache). I was keeping my front-end and back-end inside different projects on eclipse just to have everything cleaner.

However, i needed to make an ajax call (Http Post request) from the jQuery to the php server. I always get the error : `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://193.164.4.112/Server_CityInfo/whereSubscribed.php. Origin http://localhost is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.`

I looked about the error and i found out that it has to do with the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

I also read that possible solutions to solve this error are to use CORS , JSONP or a proxy. However , from the definition of the error i understand that by simply keeping the files in the same directory would solve the problem right? So what i did is moved all the frond-end files , into my back-end directory and tried to run again the html pages to make the request.

*Boom!* I get the same error again.. Am i doing something wrong here? Shouldnt it work now that they are in the same directory?

Comment: What do you mean by *"moved all the frond-end files , into my back-end directory"*?

Comment: moved my html files with my php files so that they are both in same directory.. Before i could get my html : 192.168.2.1/clientSide/example.html and my php : 192.168.2.1/serverSide/example.php . Now i deleted the clientSide directory and moved all the files to the serverSide directory. Everything works great now..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> simply keeping the files in the same directory would solve the problem right

No. They must be on the same origin (protocol, hostname, port).

You have:

```
http  193.164.4.112  80 (default for HTTP) 
http  localhost      80 (default for HTTP)
```

`193.164.4.112` is not `localhost` so you hit the same origin policy.

`193.164.4.112` and `localhost` might resolve to the same machine, be handled by the same webserver, and be served the same files, but the browser does not know that. The URLs must match.

Comment: +1. Correct me if i'm wrong, instead of using absolute url, relative url would also solve the problem

Comment: Yes, that should work (so long as the "might" in the last paragraph of the answer is what is actually happening)

Comment: Ok i solved the problem like this: I was typing in my browser localhost/pathToHTML . Instead of that i actually typed ip/pathToHTML and works! So in the end i CAN solve this by just keeping the files in the same directory right? I only had the problem because i was trying locally and had this localhost vs ip error. But my users that will be in other pcs , wont have any kind of issue right?

Comment: As I said, the directory doesn't matter. It's everything up to the local part of the URL that does.